# Sort by the reverse of the words

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, zsh

How can I sort a list of words

```
apple
banana
orange
healthy
```

by the reverse of the words, the result should be

```
banana
orange
apple
healthy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rev` utility to reverse lines characterwise. Then `rev` again.

```
$ cat input.txt | rev | sort | rev
banana
orange
apple
healthy
```

#### Edit 1

As pointed out by [@dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13919668/dan), the better solution is to do `rev input.txt | sort | rev`.

Comment: You should use `rev input.txt` instead of cat. But this is definitely the simplest method.

Comment: @dan why's that better?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly just because it's always nice to have a chance to recall `perl`:

```
perl -nE 'push @a, scalar reverse $_  }  { print scalar reverse $_ foreach sort @a' input-file
```

or

```
perl -nE 'push @a, $_  }  { print foreach (sort { (scalar reverse $a) cmp (scalar reverse $b) } @a) ' input-file
```

or

```
perl -e 'my @a = <>; print foreach (sort { (scalar reverse $a) cmp (scalar reverse $b) } @a)'
```